# how can I hide status bar in Android Galaxy tab 10.1?

Tags: android, uistatusbar

One of my customer want to  run their application on top always, so they want to hide the status bar on galaxy tab 10.1, p7500. is that possible?
Some one has posted some way to Android HoneyComb. we've try it on Galaxy tab 7500, without ROOT access, and it doesn't work. do some one has the same experience? please help.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can use the FullScreen Theme as explained in [this](http://www.vogella.de/blog/2011/02/28/android-hidding-the-status-and-title-bar/) article.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way how to hide that bar at the bottom of the screen (Galaxy Tab 2 10.1), however, using this method will make the bar appear when interacting with the touch screen.

If that is what you want, you can do it with the following code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN);
    getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE);
    ...
}
```

and

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

    getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE);

    return true;
}
```

Put these two snippets into your Activity code.
[This](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION) doc helped me a lot.

Answer (score -1):

you can use following code in oncreate method

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    setContentView(R.layout.main);
```

and you can also achived that in mention in manifest file

```
 <activity android:name=".Myproject"
              android:label="@string/app_name"
              android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
              android:screenOrientation="portrait">
```

Comment: you can not hide the status bar in galaxy tab 10.1 using this method though it works with other devices.